# RKResponseDescriptor with custom uRL

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit

What is the best approach in this case?

I've got this path to the milestones resource:

```
GET: {baseURL}/rest/v2/common/plans/{id}/milestones
```

and also this path to a different resource:

```
GET: {baseURL}/rest/v2/common/plans/{id}/statistics
```

In order to parse it properly I need to define the descriptor before any request is issued:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = 
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:...
```

with a properly defined path. I considered responseDescriptor always as a static instance, that does not need to be recreated through the app lifetime (before that I was using the request's body).

But in the case of the path above the {id} changes path nature to the dynamic one. Should I always redefine the responseDescriptor whenever I send a request with a different {id}? Defining the path with {baseURL}/rest/v2/common/plans/ is ambiguous.

Using RK version 0.26.0.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a path `pattern` for a reason:

```
@"/rest/v2/common/plans/:id/milestones"
```

Note also that using `/rest/v2/common/plans/` is an incomplete path and won't be a match.

Comment: Thank you Wain. Is there any description with a valid path pattern syntax? Is :id a sort of keyword?